# I copied the exact same code from getbootstrap for the fluid navbar header and now the navbar toggle when i shrink the webpage doesn't respond

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Store Home</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css"  type="text/css"/>
<style>
    div#headermenu > div{
        float: left;
        margin:0px 0px 0px 10px;
    }
    a{
        text-decoration:none;
        color:#000; 
    }
    a:hover{
        color:#000;
        text-decoration:none;   
    }
    a:active{color:#000;text-decoration:none;}
    a:visited{color:#000;text-decoration:none;}
    div.dropmenus{
        display:none;
        z-index:2;

    }
    div.dropmenus > a{
        display:block;
        text-decoration:none;
        color:#000; 
    }
    button{
        margin:4px; 
    }
</style>
<script src="js/getID.js"> </script>
<script type="text/x-javascript">

var ma = ["dropmenu1","dropmenu2","dropmenu3","dropmenu4","dropmenu5"];
function dropMenu(x){
    for(var m in ma){
        if(ma[m] != x){
                document.getElementById(ma[m]).style.display = "none";
        }
    }
    if( document.getElementById(x).style.display == "block"){
        document.getElementById(x).style.display = "none";
    }else{
        document.getElementById(x).style.display = "block"; 
    }
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<!--<?php include_once("template-header.php");?> -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" style="margin-bottom:5px;">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Joe Carlo Saber W serge</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Help</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" action="search.php"  method="post" style="margin-bottom:4px;margin-top:4px;">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="search">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info" style="margin-bottom:4px;">Search</button>
      </form>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li> 
            <a href="#" class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart" ></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>

<div id="headermenu">
    <div id="cont1">
        <button class="btn btn-default">
        <a href="#" onClick="return false;" onmouseover="dropMenu('dropmenu1')">computer parts </a>
        <span class="caret"> </span>
        </button>
        <div id="dropmenu1" class="dropmenus" >
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"><a href="#"> item 1</a></button><br>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"> <a href="#"> item 1</a></button><br>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"><a href="#"> item 1</a></button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="cont2">
        <button class="btn btn-default">
        <a href="#" onClick="return false;" onmouseover="dropMenu('dropmenu2')">Computers </a>
        <span class="caret"> </span>
        </button>
        <div id="dropmenu2" class="dropmenus" >
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"><a href="#"> item 1</a></button><br>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"><a href="#"> item 1</a></button><br>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"><a href="#"> item 1</a></button><br>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="cont3">
        <button class="btn btn-default">
        <a href="#" onClick="return false;" onmouseover="dropMenu('dropmenu3')">Accessories </a>
        <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <div id="dropmenu3" class="dropmenus" >
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"><a href="#"> item 1</a></button><br>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"> <a href="#"> item 1</a></button><br>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"><a href="#"> item 1</a></button>
        </div>
    </div>
        <div id="cont4">
        <button class="btn btn-default">
        <a href="#" onClick="return false;" onmouseover="dropMenu('dropmenu4')">Gaming </a>
        <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <div id="dropmenu4" class="dropmenus" >
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"><a href="#"> item 1</a></button><br>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"> <a href="#"> item 1</a></button><br>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"><a href="#"> item 1</a></button>
        </div>
    </div>
        <div id="cont5">
        <button class="btn btn-default">
        <a href="#" onClick="return false;"onmouseover="dropMenu('dropmenu5')">Networking </a>
        <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <div id="dropmenu5" class="dropmenus" >
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"><a href="#"> item 1</a></button><br>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"> <a href="#"> item 1</a></button><br>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"><a href="#"> item 1</a></button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--add new categories here. -->
</div>


<div id="pageContent" onmousedown="dropMenu()" style="height:500px;"> </div>
<script src="js/jquery-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" href="js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my code. The dropdown didn't work for me, so I had to make one from js.

I am adding the jquery to the bottom of the page and I also tried to add the other jquery from the bootstrap source code and still nothing worked I have js enabled in my browser.

Answer (score 2):

You are not declaring the scripts the right way. Use `src` instead of `href`

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>
```